# Mercurial Precommit Hook (запрет слияния с конкретной веткой по имени)

Tags: hook, mercurial, hg

Добрый день. В данный момент на проекте периодически возникает ситуация, когда по неопытности или недосмотру разработчик сливает в master либо в рабочую ветку задачи изменения из тестовой ветки (staging). 
Почитал и понял, что при помощи precommit hook-а на python можно вроде решить проблему (т.е. перед коммитом анализировать сам факт merge и то, что слияние идет из staging, и откатывать коммит).
Однако не нашел примеров для mercurial, хотя, думаю, ситуация распространенная. Было бы круто, если кто-то поделится источником или примерами.

Comment: Нашел пример подобного хука [ссылка](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HookExamples#Precommit:_disallow_bad_branch_and_bad_merge) . Возьму его за основу.